# How to protect my script from copying and modifying in it?

Tags: security, tcl, expect

I created expect script for customer and i fear to customize it like he want without returning to me so I tried to encrypt it but i didn't find a way for it
Then I tried to convert it to excutable but some commands was recognized by active tcl like "send" command even it is working perfectly on red hat

So is there a way to protect my script to be reading?

Thanks

Comment: I've flagged this as off-topic since its content may be better suited on security.se. Before you post a question like this, though, you might want to clarify some things along the lines of what you're trying to protect, who you're trying to protect it from, why you need to protect it, and what the consequences of failing to protect it might be.

Comment: I trying to protect the source copy from copying and modifying and code is expect so i don't see it is off tag if you like, i can add security in above tags

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's better suited for https://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

It's usually enough to just package the code in a form that the user can't directly look inside. Even the smallest of speed-bump stops them.

You can use [`sdx qwrap`](https://wiki.tcl.tk/3411) to parcel your script up into a starkit. Those are reasonably resistant to random user poking, while being still technically open (the `sdx` tool is freely available, after all). You can convert the `.kit` file it creates into an executable by merging it with a packaged runtime.

In short, it's basically like this (with some complexity glossed over):

```
tclkit sdx.kit qwrap myapp.tcl
tclkit sdx.kit unwrap myapp.kit
# Copy additional assets into myapp.vfs if you need to
tclkit sdx.kit wrap myapp.exe -runtime C:\path\to\tclkit.exe
```

More discussion is [here](http://wiki.tcl.tk/10558), the tclkit runtimes are [here](http://tclkits.rkeene.org/fossil/wiki/Downloads), and sdx itself can be obtained in `.kit`-packaged form [here](https://chiselapp.com/user/aspect/repository/sdx/index). Note that the runtime you use to run sdx does *not* need to be the same that you package; you can deploy code for other platforms than the one you are running from. This is a *packaging* phase action, not a compilation or linking.

---

Against more sophisticated users (i.e., not Joe Ordinary User) you'll want the Tcl Compiler out of the ActiveState TclDevKit. It's a code-obscurer formally (it doesn't actually improve the performance of anything) and the TDK isn't particularly well supported any more, but it's the main current solution for commercial protection of Tcl code. I'm on a small team working on a true compiler that will effectively offer much stronger protection, but that's not yet released (and really isn't ready yet).

Comment: Do you know if any of those tclkits bundles expect? It's not obvious from a casual glance.

Comment: Or would the "libexpect" libraries be "additional assets"?

Comment: I tried it already and tcldevkit can't bundle expect and if it worked for you, please provide tcldevkit version or a way to update expect library in tcldevkit                         i tried to a way to update expect library in tcl but i didn't find clear way to it

Answer (score 0):

One way is to store the essential code running in your server as back-end. Just give the user a fron-end application to do the requests. This way essential processes are on your control, and user cannot access that code.